# iOS react-native CameraRoll loads too slowly.

Tags: ios, react-native, camera-roll

With react-native, I implemented IOS CameraRoll that fetches 300 images from 'Camera Roll' Album on first and keep fetching 300 images whenever scroll reaches the end. Below is My code. 
**SalmonCameraRoll.js**

```
import React from 'react'

import {
  View,
  Text,
  TouchableHighlight,
  Modal,
  StyleSheet,
  Button,
  CameraRoll,
  Image,
  Dimensions,
  ScrollView,
  FlatList,
} from 'react-native'

import Share from 'react-native-share';
import RNFetchBlob from 'react-native-fetch-blob';

let styles
const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window')
const fetchAmount = 300;


class SalmonCameraRoll extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Salmon Camera Roll',
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      photos: [],
      // index: null,
      lastCursor: null,
      noMorePhotos: false,
      loadingMore: false,
      refreshing: false,
    };
    this.tryGetPhotos = this.tryGetPhotos.bind(this);
    this.getPhotos = this.getPhotos.bind(this);
    this.appendPhotos = this.appendPhotos.bind(this);
    this.renderImage = this.renderImage.bind(this);
    this.onEndReached = this.onEndReached.bind(this);
    this.getPhotos({first: fetchAmount, assetType: 'Photos'});
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.subs = [
      this.props.navigation.addListener('didFocus', () => {
        this.getPhotos({first: fetchAmount, assetType: 'Photos'});
      }),
    ];
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.subs.forEach(sub => sub.remove());
  }

  tryGetPhotos = (fetchParams) => {
    if (!this.state.loadingMore) {
      this.setState({ loadingMore: true }, () => { this.getPhotos(fetchParams)})
    }
  }

  getPhotos = (fetchParams) => {
    if (this.state.lastCursor) {
      fetchParams.after = this.state.lastCursor;
    }

    CameraRoll.getPhotos(fetchParams).then(
      r => this.appendPhotos(r)
    )
  }

  appendPhotos = (data) => {
    const photos = data.edges;
    const nextState = {
      loadingMore: false,
    };

    if (!data.page_info.has_next_page) {
      nextState.noMorePhotos = true;
    }

    if (photos.length > 0) {
      nextState.lastCursor = data.page_info.end_cursor;
      nextState.photos = this.state.photos.concat(photos);
      this.setState(nextState);
    }
  }

  onEndReached = () => {
    if (!this.state.noMorePhotos) {
      this.tryGetPhotos({first: fetchAmount, assetType: 'Photos'});
    }
  }

  renderImage = (photo, index) => {
    return (
      <TouchableHighlight
        style={{borderTopWidth: 1, borderRightWidth: 1, borderColor: 'white'}}
        key={index}
        underlayColor='transparent'
        onPress={() => {
            this.props.navigation.navigate('Camera', { backgroundImageUri: photo.node.image.uri })
          }
        } 
      >
        <Image
          style={{
            width: width/3,
            height: width/3
          }}
          representation={'thumbnail'}
          source={{uri: photo.node.image.uri}}
        />
      </TouchableHighlight>
    )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.modalContainer}>
            <FlatList
              numColumns={3}
              data={this.state.photos}
              initialNumToRender={fetchAmount}
              onEndReachedThreshold={500}
              onEndReached={this.onEndReached}
              refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
              onRefresh={() => this.tryGetPhotos({first: fetchAmount, assetType: 'Photos'})}
              keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
              renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
                this.renderImage(item, index)
              )}
            />
        </View>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  modalContainer: {
    // paddingTop: 20,
    flex: 1,
  },
  scrollView: {
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    flexDirection: 'row'
  },
  shareButton: {
    position: 'absolute',
    width,
    padding: 10,
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0
  }
})

export default SalmonCameraRoll
```

Problem is that in circumstance of a lot of images(about 10000 images) in 'Camera Roll' album, each image component was loaded so slowly that it was also loaded too slowly when scrolling accordingly.

In other famous apps like Facebook or Instagram, it loads all images quickly at once without fetching whenever scroll reaches end.

How can i make my Image component load fast? Or best of all(if possible), how can i make my CameraRoll load all images quickly at once without fetching whenever scroll reaches end?

Thank you.

Comment: A search with "react native camera roll iOS slow" or something like that finds several similar questions in Stack Overflow. Did you check all of the suggestions in those? In any case, I would guess 300 is too many to fetch in real time even from local flash storage. You need to do some proper windowing with a buffer to make it feel seamless.

Comment: Unable to load all the images now

Comment: @doublejtoh Try to fetch it asynchronously and then load it from your local state. I think that would save time in fetching.

Comment: Did you have any sample code. In my case all the images are refreshing again and again until the last set of images to load. So it looks like flickering and reloading of screen. Somtimes it shows only first 40 images